# Qt multithreaded app segfault

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I have a `Qt` application where I started getting a `SIGSEGV` in **release mode only** and when I built and linked with debug symbols on, I got a call stack like this:

```
0 ntdll!LdrFindResourceEx_U
1 ntdll!ZwWriteRequestData
2 KERNELBASE!InterlockExchange
3 ??
4 ??
5 WaitForMultipleObjectsEx
6 WaitForMultipleObjects
7 qt_adopted_thread_watcher_function
8 ??
```

In a thread different from the main thread.

It usually happens somewhere after calling `QApplication::restoreOverrideCursor()` or `QApplication::processEvents()` in a loop with heavy processing.

I say usually and after, because in rare cases it doesn't happen or it doesn't happen immediately, but after a few seconds.

I'm not starting any `QThreads` before that place in code, so I have no idea what could be causing it.

This is the description of `qt_adopted_thread_watcher_function` I found in the *Qt open source*:

```
This function loops and waits for native adopted threads to finish.
When this happens it derefs the QThreadData for the adopted thread to make sure it gets cleaned up properly
```

I'm not manually starting any `QThreads`, so why would this happen?

Comment: looks like this bug: http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/36557-QThread-internal-error-while-waiting-for-adopted-threads-87 does any other part of you code start non-QThread threads?

Comment: @PeterT yes, there is a third-party library that has its own threads, however they are in no way connected to Qt, how would Qt know about them?

Comment: the issue seems to be a non-QT thread calling some Qt function